# ¿error bibliotecas no such file directory?

Tags: c

estoy trabando con bibliotecas pero no se porque me dice que no encuentra el archivo cuando todas estan en la mismas carpeta de archivos este es mi archivo `overflow.h`

```
#include <iostream>
void suma(int n1,int n2);
```

este es mi archivo `overflow.c`

```
#include "overflow.h"
void suma(int n1,int n2){
    return n1+n2;
}
```

y esta es mi función principal

```
#include "overflow.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x1;
    cin>>x1;
    int x2;
    cin>>x2;
    suma(x1,x2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: compilas manualmente o usas un IDE?, que error sale?, cual es la estructura de directorios del proyecto?

Comment: hola,estoy usando GEANY no se si es un IDe pero creo que si ,el error que me sale es :no such file directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que suelo hacer cuando trabajo con mis propias bibliotecas es lo siguiente:

Escribo todo el código de la biblioteca en mi archivo .h:

Así es como debería quedar tu archivo.h:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int suma(int n1,int n2){
return n1+n2;
}
```

La función suma es de tipo entero porque retorna un valor entero (la suma de los dos números).

Lo guardo en la misma carpeta de mi archivo principal. Tu función principal debería de quedarte de la siguiente manera:

```
#include "overflow.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){

    int x1;
    cin>>x1;
    int x2;
    cin>>x2;

    cout<<"La suma de los números es = "<<suma(x1,x2);
    return 0;
}
```

De esta manera puedes crear tus propias bibliotecas para minimizar código en tu programa principal

Comment: El problema de este enfoque, es que si incluyes el archivo `overflow.h` en varios archivos `.c`, tendrás varias definiciones de funciones con el mismo nombre y esto causa un error en tiempo de enlazado. Hay muchas desventajas con este enfoque, por ejemplo, no se aprovecha la compilación incremental (compilar solo los archivos con modificaciones recientes). Lo ideal sería tener cada definición de X función en un archivo `.c`.